# How can I request access to Azure Machine Learning resources via OAuth?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-machine-learning-service

Many APIs in Azure allow an App Registration to request "API Permissions." With a multi-tenant app, a user or admin is presented with a consent screen allowing the user to grant permission to the those resources to the application. The permissions are captured in the `requiredResourceAccess` parameter of the application manifest.

However, it doesn't seem like Azure ML Resources can be granted in this way. I ran the following command to review all the Application Roles and OAuth Scopes defined for Applications/Service-Principle in my tenant and don't see anything defined for the various Azure Machine Learning Services applications:

```
az ad sp list --all --query "[].{Name:appDisplayName, Roles:appRoles, Scopes:oauth2PermissionScopes}"
```

Is there another way to request consent via OAuth for a resource? Ideally we'd like to get permissions for actions `Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/*/read`

I can create a role with that specific Action set. And I can via CLI or the GUI assign that role to SP that is created for our application (with some dummy permission like User.Read), but this seems cumbersome and requires additional work from an administrator.

What alternatives exist? Are there some undocumented `resourceAccess` GUIDs out there for AzureML? Can I somehow craft a Role for App Registration that will be applied to future tenants that authorize the app? (It looks like that is possible for custom permissions, but I want to use the out of the box AzureML actions).

Comment: Can you share some example of the APIs you'd like to be able to use your app to call?